# Trying to install pre-configured virtual box using vagrant. Init failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, virtualbox, vagrant

first of all I'm pretty new at this but i'm trying to follow along installing an open source crowd funding platform using a guide

https://github.com/danielweinmann/catarse/wiki/Pre-Configured-Catarse-Virtual-Box-using-Vagrant-%28Ubuntu-11.10-AMD64%29

I installed vagrant and virtual box all fine including the download of the image.

The problem is when I try to initialize it using the command:

```
vagrant init Ubuntu_11.10_amd64-Catarse-Master
```

The system responds with the following error:

```
Tiagos-MacBook-Pro:catarse_vagrant tiagomartins$ vagrant init Ubuntu_11.10_amd64-Catarse-Master
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/init.rb:28:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Users/tiagomartins/catarse_vagrant/Vagrantfile (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/init.rb:28:in `open'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/init.rb:28:in `open'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/init.rb:28:in `execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:167:in `cli'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/bin/vagrant:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:19:in `load'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:19:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong and what's the best approach to fix it.

Thanks a lot!!

Tiago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, Vagrant cannot access `/Users/tiagomartins/catarse_vagrant/Vagrantfile` due to permission settings for that file.

Changing the file's or parent folder's permissions ([`chmod`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/chmod.1.html)/[`chown`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/chown.8.html)) should resolve the problem.